# Is this the correct way to allow another view mode to access a view models properties?

Tags: architecture, swiftui

I have a single SwiftUi view linked to two view models. One manages the stopwatch, the other manages the location info. At some location point I need to know what the time is on the stopwatch.

The approach I have taken is to set an observer on the stopwatch as shown in the diagram and the snippets of code below it.

[image]

```
class StopWatchManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stopWatchTime = "00:00:00.0"

    static let shared = StopWatchManager()
    
    private init() {
        
    }

    ...

}

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var stopWatch = StopWatchManager.shared

    ....

    let time = stopWatch.stopWatchTime

    .... 

}
```

It does work, however is this the correct way to connect these two controllers together such that the LocationManager can obtain the stopwatch time? If not, what is best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObservedObject` wrapper works only in SwiftUI. To observe in class publisher of other class you can to use the following approach

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    private var time: String = "00:00:00.0"
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        cancellable = StopWatchManager.shared.$stopWatchTime
            .sink { [weak self] time in
                self?.time = time         // << update local when remote changes
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the class in SceneDelegate and include it as an environment object for rootViewController.

Then in the views you can have:
@EnvironmentObject var stopWatchManager: StopWatchManager
...
let time = stopWatchManager.stopWatchTime